# Appending content to file gives permission denied error

Tags: shell-script, sudo, io-redirection, cat

I am trying to append some config to another file like this

```
sudo cat config/add-this.yml >> ~/docker-compose.yml
```

via shell script. But trying this gives me a `Permission denied` error.

How can I simply append some content to another file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the shell performs redirections *before* the command is executed.

In this case. unless the permissions of the file into which data is to be added allow appending, a *permission denied* error results.

You can circumvent this by doing:

```
sudo sh -c 'cat config/add-this.yml >> ~/docker-compose.yml'
```

Comment: So it would also work if I would set `chmod 777 docker-compose.yml`, right?

Comment: Yes, though opening permissions is often the wrong approach.  Some configuration files **must** have r/w permissions and only by the owner for a daemon to accept the file for processing.

Comment: What does the `-c`-flag do?

Comment: `-c` reads and executes commands from the first non-option argument command_string, and then exits.  See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoking-Bash) .